# How do I set keyboard layout per window on Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: gnome, keyboard, keyboard-layout, window

I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.
When I was on pop OS, I was able to change keyboard layout for each window (not global layout).
Is there something similar on Ubuntu 20.04 ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Below picture is self explanatory..

Go to system settings,
Region & Language,
Input Sources,
Settings Icon,
Choose "Allow Different Sources for each window"

[image]

Or if you wish to make it via command line

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window true
```

to reset

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.desktop.input-sources per-window
```

Comment: Should I reboot after this?

Comment: @VitalyZdanevich no reboot is required.